# Changing the last found target value in a linked list (node chain)

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to figure out how to change the last found target value in a linked list to the replacement value. For example if you had a linked list such as;

`[1,'next'],[2,'next'],[3,next'],[2,none]`

How would I replace only the last 2, rather than all of them, or the first one? This is the code that I currently have;

```
walker = node_chain
if node_chain is None:
    return None
elif walker['data'] == target_val and walker['next'] is None:
    walker = node.set_data(walker, replacement_val)
    return walker
else:
    while walker['next'] is not None:
        if walker['data'] == target_val:
            node_chain = node.set_data(walker, replacement_val)
            return node_chain
        walker = node.get_next(walker)
        if walker['next'] is None and walker['data'] == target_val:
            walker = node.set_data(walker, replacement_val)
            return walker
```

So in the given code, if the target value was 2, and the replacement value was 4, it would return

`[1,'next'],[4,'next'],[3,next'],[2,none]`

rather than what I want to be returned;

`[1,'next'],[2,'next'],[3,next'],[4,none]`

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Initialize a second variable for storing the last position of target value. Just iterate through the linked list normally and whenever you find the target value, update the second variable. After you finish traversing the list, then just update the node stored in the second variable

Answer (score 0):

```
walker = node_chain
target_node = None
if node_chain is None:
    return None
else:
    while walker is not None:
        if walker['data'] == target_val:
            target_node = walker
        walker = node.get_next(walker)
    if target_node != None
        node_chain = node.set_data(target_node, replacement_val)
```

You should do something like this. I'm not sure if this works because I dont have the other functions of yours, but this should give you a general idea